# Mocha doc reporter that contains passed test information

Tags: mocha.js

I am using the MochaJS doc test reporter, but the HTML that it generates does not contain information about which tests have passed and which not. It looks something like this: http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/docs/test.html Is there any way to extract that information or any alternative that generates a PDF with information on passed/failed tests?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: In the end I modified the Mocha's doc reporter, adding the pass/fail information in the pass/fail handlers, something like (Coffeescript code):

`console.log "%s  <dt>%s &#10004; </dt> (duration: %s)", indent(), utils.escape(test.title), test.duration`

Comment: I was having a similar issue. I ended up forking mocha and creating my own  doc reporter that also embeds screenshots. Probably old news for you but thought I would add it here: https://github.com/maggiesavovska/mocha